# What is the difference between a hard switched vs soft switched architecture in power converters

Tags: power-electronics, motor-controller

I've seen many examples detailing ZVS/ZCS for boost/buck converters, but I haven't found any evidence that soft switching is a design goal for motor drivers.
Why is it difficult to soft switch a motor drive? What is the fundamental difference between a hard and soft switched converter architecture? My understanding is that a motor drive is a hard switched architecture.

Comment: Softswitching in motor drives has been used in SCR era because of it's unability to turn off with gate. The SCR must be turned of with LC circuit (or another SCR) to force the current thru them to zero. Todays the mosfets and IGBT are able to switch high power, so there is no need to softswitch.

Answer (score 1):

ZVS/ZCS requires a LC tank and the converter is resonant or quasi resonant type. It can change frequency (quasi resonant) VS. load or it implements some other modulation, for example PDM, or pulse skipping,...

Of course this is not an option for the motor control which requires a SVPWM or PWM modulation and has no LC tank, but who knows what will be in the future.